# DataGridView column bound to a read-only field must have ReadOnly set to True

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I know there must be a simple solution to this question, but I seem to be missing the answer.
I have a Visual Studio 2008 Winforms application where I created a datagridview to display data to users. In the datagridview I allow the users to edit information. One of the cells is set to read only and the users want to be able to edit this information now. When I go into the datagridview designer to set the cell to Readonly = False the change does not get saved. Does not matter what I do the change WILL not get saved. I am now looking into changing this at run time using the code below:

When I use that code I get the error mentioned in the title. It seems to me that I am stuck now... I can't change the cell to readonly = false using the Visual Studio designer. I can't set the cell to readonly = false at runtime.

Question: What am I doing wrong? Is there something else I can do? This is quite a sizable application for multiple users and this is a request made by most of the users.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Dim oDL As New MTN.BusinessLayer.MasterTables()
Dim dt As DataTable = oDL.GetTheItems() DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

Answer (score 4):

You can actually set the ReadOnly property for the DataTable column!

```
Dim dt As DataTable = oDL.GetTheItems()
dt.Columns("Selected").ReadOnly = false
DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried? (setting properties) :

```
AllowUserToAddRows = False
AllowUserToDeleteRows = False
ReadOnly = True
```

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't work.
The Grid has three columns. Two of them are textbox's and one column is a checkbox column. I can modify the textbox columns but not the CheckBox column. from some reason it won't become checked when I click it with the mouse.

Comment: Similar question was discussed before on SO forum so take a look: 
[HERE!!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084419/checkboxfield-columns-in-asp-net-gridview-are-disabled-even-if-readonly-set-to-f)

Comment: This [Link](http://pradeep1210.wordpress.com/2012/05/16/checkbox-in-header-cell-of-datagridview-control/#more-561) will probably help you solve the problem once for all. Let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

First Set DataTable ReadOnly Property False.
Then Set Gridview ReadOnly Property false.

EX-

```
DataTable dt=("Select * prom priceList");
 dt.Columns["Rate"].ReadOnly = false;

DataGrid View dgv=.dataSource=dt;
 dgv.Columns["Rate"].ReadOnly = false;
```

Comment: Please highlight the code so it'll make more clarity to answer